# Decoupling in threaded environment java

Tags: java, multithreading, design-patterns, jar

I am facing this decoupling problem. Let me explain this with example:

Say i have different classes that uses some JAR. Now this JAR keeps on getting updated and we also need to update our system along with this too. Now if there is a slight change in this JAR i have to make changes to every class, so we decided to decouple it. But these classes call the JAR classes in such a way that they make an object of it, set some flag and on the basis of that derive results. Hence every object has its own importance in every method.

Let me explain this with simple example.

Say i have a class X

```
class X {
  Base base;
  public int getCalResult(int a, int b) {
     base = new Base();
     base.setA(a);
     base.setB(b);
     return base.getResult();
  }

  public int getCalResult2(int a, int b, int c) {
     base = new Base();
     base.setA(a);
     base.setB(b);
     base.setC(c);
     return base.getResult();
  }
}

class Base { This is some legacy class inside JAR so can't change this
  int a, b, c, d;
  public setA(int a) {
    this.a = a;
  }
  public getResult() {
    return a + b + c + d;
  }
}
```

How to decouple this sort of structure and make it thread safe at the same time. Any pointers ? Any design patterns ?

I want that all the calls to JAR must be maintained in a single class, so that in case if there is change in JAR i only have to deal with single class and not all of them

What i did is

Introduced BaseProxy

```
public class BaseProxy {
  Base b;
  public static newInstance() {
    b = new Base();
  }

  public static setABCD(int a, int b) {
    b.setA(a);
    b.setB(b);
  }
}

class X {
      public int getCalResult(int a, int b) {
         BaseProxy.newInstance();
         BaseProxy.setAB(a,b);
         return BaseProxy.getResult();
 }

  public int getCalResult2(int a, int b, int c) {
     BaseProxy.newInstance();
     BaseProxy.setABC(a,b,c);
     return BaseProxy.getResult();
  }
}
```

This would have worked in single threaded env but not in mutli. I need suggestion on this. Any other better design, i am sure there is.

Comment: I don't really see what you mean by "decouple". But to make it thread-safe, just don't use a field when you could (should) use a local variable: the `base` field in X has no reason to exist.

Comment: to be precise extract out functionality from various classes into single

Comment: Unfortunately that is how it is coded.

Answer (score 1):

Few things not clear (or not ideal)
1. When you say, the legacy class in jar get updated, does it change the existing prototype or adds new functionality ? If they keep updating the definition then you are in trouble.

**To get around this**, one way is to extract an interface out of the legacy class and define a **delegate** implementing it (place it outside your calling code) and use it in calling code to reduce direct dependency. Now your delegate should talk to legacy class.

Also, whenever your legacy class changes, its only the delegate side you will need to update (unless there is complete turnaround in called functions)

Comment: It happens sometimes other team does make change to signature or deploy class in another package, and yes functionality always gets added. This JAR actually uses JNA to call native Sybase library.

Comment: Yes i have introduced the proxy class in between the two, but the way this class is used is not good. On the basis of the flags being set it calculates result. now these flags will always differ in different methods. Every method initialized new object of this. i am not able to find a way to extract that out

Comment: "To get around this, one way is to extract an interface out of the legacy class and define a delegate implementing it (place it outside your calling code) and use it in calling code to reduce direct dependency. Now your delegate should talk to legacy class."    Any design pattern for this ??

Comment: @gagan: Its not about using a design pattern (u may end up finding a name / similarity). What I am emphasizing on is - get a consistent interface    (from your other team) otherwise this will not end. Once interface is consistent behavior change should not impact you. When adding functionality, you still may have to update the calling code. Pls add more details in case you think I am misunderstanding the issue.

Comment: Why class X still need to Base class ref ? Also is it necessary to make proxy a singleton ? If its needed to make Proxy singleton, can you its access in the methods within lock ? This will fix your multithreading concern.

Comment: well i think i get it now what you are saying, and its achievable by not making methods static. instead introducing a helper class without static methods.

Comment: yup thanks for time, let me try out few things and in case i feel under confident i will ask for help. :-)